# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: asp.net

[image]

this is my webpage in which i am collecting daily reports... which is working fine. when i choose monthly reports which contain a lot of data calculation than it gives the following exception (Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.) 
in

```
DataSet datSet = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase().ExecuteDataSet("TollCollectionsReport",
            Web.ShiftID,
            Web.ShiftStatus,
            rdoShiftTimeBase.SelectedValue,
            startDate,
            endDate,
            BoothCodes,
            OperatorCodes,
            CategoryCodes,
            PaymentModesCodes,
            TimeIntervalCodes,
            ddlReportCritera.SelectedItem.Text,
            rdbtnBoothIsSimple.SelectedValue,
            rdbtnOperaotrIsSimple.SelectedValue,
            rdoShiftTypes.SelectedValue,
            rdoCategories.SelectedValue,
            rdoPaymentModes.SelectedValue,
            rdoTimeSequence.SelectedValue,
            groupingSequence,
            Session["TimeInterval"].ToString(),
            isRangeSelected);
```

this function... this function randomly generates query... here is the line after this function...

```
string query = datSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

i increased timeout of db in config file and in program ... but still am getting the same exception at `DataSet datSet = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase().ExecuteDataSet` ..this funtion call works for 30 to 40 seconds after that it crashes and throws an exception... kindly help  me out ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. 
Add this to web.config file

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
```

Or

**Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)**